# Excluding files in a Gradle multi-project in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, groovy, build

I have a simple multi-project gradle build file that I use as a base for an Intellij project, and I want to exclude some files from the build, so I use 'excludes' on the compile task (which I have just copy-pasted), as shown in the listing.

This seems to be working from the command line, but it doesn't work from within Intellij i.e. excluded files still get included in the compilation.

Any suggestions? (Gradle 2.10, Intellij 15.0.3)

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'application'
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.5'
        testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4'
    }
}

project(':projfoo') {
    group = 'com.bshishani.projfoo'
}

project(':projbar') {
    group = 'com.bshishani.projbar'
    dependencies {
        compile project(':projfoo')
        testCompile project(':projfoo')
    }

    compileGroovy {
        excludes = ['**/aaa.groovy', '**/bbb.groovy']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude directories programmatically from IntelliJ project by configuring the `idea` plugin:

For example:

```
idea {
  module {
    excludeDirs += [file("myproject/dir")]
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to exclude files (or globs) from compilation in IntelliJ. If this isn't possible, it may be preferable to move all of the "special" sources to their own directory.

More information about [IntelliJ Module config with Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html)

Comment: This is still functionally different from the 'Mark Directory As -> Excluded' option. The content won't participate in compilation but will interact with IDE features like search/replace

Answer (score 0):

To mark a folder in the source as excluded from the IDEA complier you must first right click a folder in the projects view.

Right click folder > Mark directory as > Excluded

[image: Marking a folder as Excluded in IntelliJ IDEA]

Comment: Thx. This is a Gradle project, so what's desired is to be able to control Intellij behaviour by making changes to the Gradle build file.